# How to find which port is listening certain process on linux?

Tags: linux, process, port

My java program need to know, which port is using certain process to send there http queries, how can I find port of process in linux by process name of pid?

Answer (score 3):

This will show only the port:

```
netstat -plantu | grep <pid> | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I don't know why but port of tomcat is showing 8005, and if get to localhost:8080 tomcat page is shown, I tried to get process by port  8080 and found the same process as for 8005.

Comment: I don't know a lot about tomcat, but I know that it uses port 8080 to serve pages and 8005 to receive commands. That's why you see both ports related to tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple from command line, but you need superuser privileges to do so.
Run `netstat --inet -apn | grep PID or process name'.

Comment: $sudo netstat --inet -apn | grep 22

The output might be something lile this:

tcp 0  0 0.0.0.0:22  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   4203/sshd